# deleting a big table based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle11g

i have a huge table which has no indexing on it. and indexing cant be added. i need to delete rows like this :

```
delete from table1 where id in (
select id from table2 inner join table3 on table2.col1 = table3.col1);
```

but since it has huge number of rows its taking too much time. what i can do to make it faster other than indexing (not permitted).

I am using oracle db.

Comment: Save the results you want to keep in a temporary table.  Truncate the table, and then re-insert them.

Comment: try to use CTAS (create table as select) it's much faster;

Comment: What @GordonLinoff said, then index!